Issues installing ROS2 humble on TurtleBot3 Burger (ld08_driver)
I am trying to install ROS2 on my TurtleBot3 Burger. I am following this tutorial: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/sbc_setup/#sbc-setup
Specifically
colcon build --symlink-install --parallel-workers 1

It has been building for the past 20 hours and it has still not been completed (it is stuck at 28% for 20 hours now).
It is specifically getting stuck when trying to process the ld08_driver
What I have tried so far:

I removed the parallel workers flag (the result is the same, refer attached image).


Any help on how to fix this will be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

This worked for me:
If you have only 1 GB or less of RAM, you’re likely running out of memory. When the system runs out of RAM and swap, compilation can get stuck or take too long. I used the following commands to increase the swap space:

sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab

Then I changed the colcon command to the following to make sure it builds one job at a time.

colcon build --symlink-install --executor sequential --parallel-workers 1

